# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements while creating hierarchical columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I was going through the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) about the hierarchical indexing in Pandas. I tried testing the examples from it to create an empty dataframe with hierarchical indexing:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [6]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels = [['first', 'second'], ['a', 'b']], labels = [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

However, it throws an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-dd823f9b8d22> in <module>()
----> 1 df.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels = [['first', 'second'], ['a', 'b']], labels = [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   2755         try:
   2756             object.__getattribute__(self, name)
-> 2757             return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   2758         except AttributeError:
   2759             pass

pandas/src/properties.pyx in pandas.lib.AxisProperty.__set__ (pandas/lib.c:44873)()

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _set_axis(self, axis, labels)
    446 
    447     def _set_axis(self, axis, labels):
--> 448         self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
    449         self._clear_item_cache()
    450 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
   2800             raise ValueError('Length mismatch: Expected axis has %d elements, '
   2801                              'new values have %d elements' %
-> 2802                              (old_len, new_len))
   2803 
   2804         self.axes[axis] = new_labels

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 4 elements
```

I don't see any problem with my code. Any ideas what is happening?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that you have an empty data frame which has zero columns, and you are trying to assign a four columns multi-index to it; If you create an empty data frame of four columns initially, the error will be gone:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 4)))    
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels = [['first', 'second'], ['a', 'b']], labels = [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Or you can create empty data frame with the multi-index as follows:

```
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex(levels = [['first', 'second'], ['a', 'b']], labels = [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])    
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=multi_index)

df
#   first    second
#  a    b   a     b
```

Comment: Thanks! As an aside, I have never seen anything like `pd.np.`. Can you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: You're welcome. `pd.np` is a short hand for `import numpy as np; np...`, so you can access numpy functions from the `pandas.np` module without having to import numpy module explicitly.

Comment: That's new. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, using `pd.np` will be deprecated soon; so don't use it. Just import numpy directly in any new code you write.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not require `numpy`:

```py
# create empty DataFrame with 4 columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = range(4))

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex(
    levels = [['first', 'second'], ['a', 'b']], 
    codes = [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
)
```

(Note: I changed `labels` to `codes` because that was changed in Pandas v1.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you have used df.loc[, <col_name>]= value
and you have not wrapped the condition within double brackets (). Make sure to always insert conditions in loc statements in double brackets.

It should be something similar to the one below:

df.loc[<(condition1) & (condition2)>, <col_name>]= value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).